# Seeking alternative to Collector for ArcGIS for creating new records in Related Table in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, software-recommendations, arcgis-collector

I'm hosting a Web Mapping Application on ArcGIS Online. The design consists of two parts.

1. A Feature Layer called Project Description which visualizes the location of every Project in my database
2. A Related Table called Project Milestone which logs milestone updates to the Projects within a table.

The relationship between the two objects results from a one-to-many Relationship Class (One Project Description can have many Milestones). It is the exact same setup as the Hydrants and Inspections layers in [this example](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/) demonstrating how to set up the ability to create new records in Related Tables by using Collector for ArcGIS.

However, the client which commissioned this Web Mapping Application *cannot use Collector for ArcGIS*. They are a federal agency and cannot legally require that all of their employees have smartphones.

Is there a good alternative to Collector  for ArcGIS available which allows for creating new records in a related table within ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the [out-of-the-box Edit widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/widget-edit.htm) for web apps supports this? If not, it seems like you could write a custom widget to support editing related records.  Last time I checked, AGOL doesn't allow you to upload custom widgets, but you might be able to build a Web app using WAB, then [import the app into AGOL](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/create-import-app.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_CD827E29515941F490AF21F6F2404E35) (never tried this).

Comment: Thanks for the note Kirk. The Edit widget does not support this, and I agree that it would seem like writing a custom widget would be the next step - however that is a daunting task with an unknown timelime, & I'm not even sure I could implement it. Hoping to find a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

If you can accept a very loosely-coupled solution, you could implement a small .NET web-UI based 'Milestone editor' which would:

- be deployed onto a web-server, even the AGOL server if available,
- launch from a URL link on your Project feature in AGOL (and pass a Project_PK)
- accept user input for Milestone details
- post the Milestone details (including Project FK) to the related AGOL table using the REST API.

Such a tool would be run largely independent of whatever AGOL-based Project editing tool was implemented, as long as the launching URL was configured in AGOL dialog.

Again, this is very loosely coupled and, without proper constraints, you could end up with 'orphaned' Milestone records -- milestones which do not refer to any Project feature.  But it is a comparatively low-cost implementation.